# Node.js and Backbone.js Router on the server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

Does anyone use Backbone Router in the node.js server?
Maybe some extensions which are allowing this?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/flatiron/director (a component of http://flatironjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

We do but we´ve just started. Airbnb also seems to have embraced it  http://nerds.airbnb.com/weve-launched-our-first-nodejs-app-to-product

Comment: Oh now I saw that you asked about the router. We only use events and collections. I think AirBnb uses it mostly for pre-rendering views and such